# Why do all elements for the array object class repeat last entered data C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a class BankAccount with an array made of BankAccount objects. Each object has the name, balance, bank account type, and so forth for each customer. The way this is implemented is through a BankAccount* customers[10] as the classes private field memeber. Customers is then filled with objects made from the chosen constructor. Each piece of data that makes up each object which is an element to customers are all input by the user. In display() data is output, however the problem is that the last inputed object is repeated for each element to customers. Why does this repeat like this? Any help or advice would be great!

```
BankAccount::BankAccount() :  customers()
{
setAcctAmt();
}

void BankAccount::work()
{
for (int x = 0; x < accountAmount; x++)
{
    bool t = true;
    string theName, sT;
    double balance, iRate;
    cout << "Enter the name for account " << x + 1 << endl;
    cin >> theName;
    while (t)
    {
        if (t == false)
            exit;
        cout << "Bank Account type: Checking or Saving" << endl;
        cin >> sT;
        string s;
        s = sT.substr(0, 1);
        if (s == "c")
        {
            sT = "Checking Account ";
            cout << "Input checking balance: ";
            cin >> balance;
            iRate = 0.02;
            makeAcctNum();
            constAcct(theName, balance, iRate, sT); // This is where customers is constructed and data is imput from parameters
            t = false;
        }
        else if (s == "s")
        {
            sT = "Savings Account ";
            cout << "Input saving balance: ";
            cin >> balance;
            iRate = 0.07;
            makeAcctNum();
            constAcct(theName, balance, iRate, sT); // The constructed object
            t = false;
        }
        else
            cout << "Error, enter checking or saving!" << endl;
    }
}
display(); // This is the display function to display all constructed objects of customers
}
// This is the display function
void BankAccount::display()
{

for (int i = 0; i < accountAmount; i++)
{
    cout << customers[i]->getAcctNum() << " " << customers[i]->getName() << " " << customers[i]->getType() << " " << customers[i]->getRate()
                    << " " << customers[i]->getBalance();
}

}
// This is the constructor that will build each customers element as customer data
BankAccount::BankAccount(string* nam, int* acctNumber, double* balanc, double* rat, string* typ)
{
rate = rat;
account = acctNumber;
name = nam;
type = typ;
bal = balanc;
}

void BankAccount::deleteStuff()
{
delete name, type, bal, rate, account, customers;
}
// This constructs each customers element
void BankAccount::constAcct(string n, double ba, double r, string t)
{

nameS = n;
balD = ba;
rateD = r;
typeS = t;
name = &nameS;
account = &acctNumber;
rate = &rateD;
bal = &balD;
type = &typeS;
for (int i = 0; i < accountAmount; i++)
{
    BankAccount* b = new BankAccount(name, account, bal, rate, type);
    customers[i] = b;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this comment and line of code:

> ```
> // This is where customers is constructed and data is imput from parameters    
> constAcct(theName, balance, iRate, sT);
> ```

It seems your intention is to create a new account using the `constAcct` method.
Looking at that method:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < accountAmount; i++)
> {
>     BankAccount* b = new BankAccount(name, account, bal, rate, type);
>     customers[i] = b;
> }
> ```

You are rewriting all entries in the `customers` array with a `new BankAccount` constructed from the same parameters (whatever the last parameters were).

To fix this, you should replace the above loop with something like this:

```
customers[lastAccountIndex++] = new BankAccount(name, account, bal, rate, type);
```

Here `lastAccountIndex` is a variable to keep track of the number of accounts already added.

Comment: I made a variable and incremented it like that and now it seems to have a problem with bal in my getBalance function Unhandled exception at 0x011C9836 in Week1_Lab2_Ex16.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000030. says it is NULL how is this so?